# 3 last distinct values of a list taken from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of orders (each order is a dict) which looks like this (simplified version) :

```
[{'name' : XXX,
  'id' : { 'order_id_local' : 'xxx_001'}},
 {'name' : XXX,
  'id' : { 'order_id_local' : 'xxx_002'}},
 {'name' : XXX,
  'id' : {}},
 {'name' : XXX,
  'id' : { 'order_id_local' : 'xxx_002'}},
 {'name' : XXX,
  'id' : { 'order_id_local' : 'xxx_003'}},
  ...]
```

As you can see there could be duplicate for the key `'order_id_local'` but also nothing.
What I would like to do is to get the last distinct 3 `'order_id_local'` in a list, beginning from the last one. 
Here it will be `['xxx_0003', 'xxx_002', 'xxx_001']`.

What i did is :

```
 id_orders = [x['id']['order_id_local'] for x in order_list if 'order_id_local' in x['id']]  
 id_orders = [x for x in id_orders if x is not None]
 id_orders = list(reversed(sorted(set(id_orders))[-3:]))
```

It works but when i see this `id_orders` three times and those nested functions, i'm wondering if there is no a more efficient and pythonic way to do this.

Comment: How large is your actual `order_list` ?

Comment: around an hundred orders per name, and i get the list for each name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension to keep track of the last index for each order_id_local and skip blank entries:

```
local_ids = {order['id']['order_id_local']:n for n,order in enumerate(data) if order['id']}
```

Then reverse sort the dictionary keys by their value and slice off the first 3:

```
sorted(local_ids.keys(), reverse=True, key=local_ids.get)[:3]
```

result:

```
['xxx_003', 'xxx_002', 'xxx_001']
```